# The Galois group and relations among the roots of a polynomial

Tags: galois-theory

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial of degree $n$, and let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ... , \alpha_n \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the $n$ distinct roots of $f(x)$.

Following Bewersdorff's "Galois Theory for Beginners" (and older sources?) I want to define the Galois group of $f(x)$ as follows.  Let $I \subset \mathbb{Q}[x_1, x_2, ... , x_n]$ be the ideal consisting of those polynomials $g(x_1, x_2, ... , x_n)$ in $n$ variables such that $$g(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ... , \alpha_n) = 0$$

I propose to call $I$ the *Galois ideal* of $f(x)$.  If there is a more standard term for this, please let me know.

Now the Galois group of $f(x)$ may be defined as the group $G \subset S_n$ consisting of those permutations $\sigma \in S_n$ such that $$g \in I \Longrightarrow g_\sigma \in I$$
where $g_\sigma$ is the polynomial $g$ transformed by permuting the variables using the permutation $\sigma$.

Certain polynomials will be trivially members of $I$ for any polynomial $f(x)$.  Specifically, $f(x_1), f(x_2), ... , f(x_n) \in I$, and also the elementary symmetric polynomials minus the coefficients of $f$ will be members, e.g. $x_{1}x_{2} ... x_{n} - (-1)^{n} c_0$, where $c_0$ is the constant coefficient of $f$.

For some ("most"?!) polynomials $f(x)$, the Galois ideal is generated *only* by these trivial members, and for such polynomials the Galois group is the full symmetric group.  To the extent that there are *non-trivial* generators of $I$, the Galois group will be a proper subgroup of $S_n$.

For example, if $f(x) = x^4 - 2$, and $\alpha_1 = \sqrt[4]{2}$, $\alpha_2 = -\sqrt[4]{2}$, $\alpha_3 = i\sqrt[4]{2}$, $\alpha_4 = -i\sqrt[4]{2}$, then the non-trivial generators of $I$ are $$g_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_1 + x_2$$ $$g_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_3 + x_4$$  Accordingly, the Galois group is generated only by the permutations $$1234 \rightarrow 2134$$ $$1234 \rightarrow 1243$$ $$1234 \rightarrow 3412$$

My question is, is there an algorithm to find the non-trivial generators of the Galois ideal?  It seems that this ideal actually gives more information about the polynomial $f(x)$ than the Galois group, since it is trivial to find the Galois group given the Galois ideal, but not conversely.

Comment: If you have Maple you can enter interface(verboseproc=3) and then eval(galois) to see how Maple calculates Galois groups.  The main galois() function calls various other functions which you can display similarly by entering eval(`galois/absres`) and so on.  Presumably one can do the same with various other systems.

Comment: 
Thanks Neil-- I don't have Maple but I did check Pari, and it has a case-by-case algorithm for poly's of degree up to 11, which I found uninspiring.  As mentioned, I'm really more interested in the Galois ideal than in the Galois group, and I'm not aware of anything that computes the non-trivial generators of this ideal.  I am going to try to look up Eisenbud's paper on primary decomposition in Inventiones 110 if I get a chance.


Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Galois ideal is one of the prime factors of the ideal generated by the trivial elements. Thus, an algorithm for primary decomposition in $\mathbb Q[x_1,...x_n]$, of which there are several, will do the trick.

Proof: The Galois ideal is prime, which is obvious from its definition. It contains the trivial ideal. Since the vanishing set of the trivial ideal has dimension $0$, all prime ideals containing it are maximal, thus all prime ideals are prime factors.

(In terms of "most", if I remember correctly, almost all polynomials with coefficients of bounded height have Galois group the full symmetric group, but I am not an expert on such things.)

Comment: 
OK, forgive me for being dense, but how does a primary decomposition in $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ take into account the particular polynomial $f(x)$?  Can you give me an example of how this works for $f(x) = x^4 - 2$ ?



Comment: It is the primary decomposition of the trivial ideal, which takes into account the particular polynomial. (Note that the trivial ideal is generated by just the elementary symmetrical polynomials minus the coefficients of $f$.)

Comment: So for that $f$ we have the equations $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$, $x_1x_2+...+x_3x_4$, $x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_l$, and $x_1x_2x_3x_4=2$. This ideal has three prime factors, one for each coset of $D_4$ in $S_4$. The first factor is generated by $x_1+x_3$, $x_2+x_4$, $x_1^2+x_2^2$, $x_2^2+x_3^2$, $x_3^2+x_4^3$, $x_4^2+x_1^2, etc. The other factors are similar, but permuted.

Comment: 
OK, I see what you mean now.  I will try to look up the decomposition algorithms.


Comment: 
I guess I was confused because the trivial ideal is determined as soon as you know $f(x)$, but to find the Galois ideal you have to specify a numbering of the roots $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ... \alpha_n$.

Maybe you're telling me that there are conjugate Galois ideals corresponding to the conjugate subgroups of the Galois group $G \subset S_n$?  I'm going to have to chew on this some more.


Comment: The Galois ideal is one of the prime factors. The other prime factors are other versions of the Galois ideal. I don't think they quite correspond to conjugate subgroups. Instead, it corresponds to the cosets in $S_n/G$. For instance, an irreducible cubic with discriminant a perfect square should have a trivial ideal that splits into two Galois ideals, each giving the same subgroup, $A_3$, since $A_3$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: We can view this explicitly in $\mathbb Q(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity. Take the equation $f(x)=x^3-2$, then one Galois ideal will have the equations $x_1-\omega x_2, x_2-\omega x_3$ while the other will have $x_3 - \omega x_2$, $x_2-\omega x_1$. Both have the same symmetry group, but they are different.

Comment: 
Thanks for your responses, Will.  The only thing I still don't understand is your comment about cosets.  Whichever version of the Galois ideal you look at, it is clear from the definition that the corresponding Galois group is indeed a group.  And a coset is not a group.

I still think the different Galois ideals must correspond to conjugate subgroups of $G \subset S_n$.  In your example, as you say, $A_3 \vartriangleleft S_3$, so $A_3$ has no distinct conjugate subgroups.  That makes sense.  I just don't see where cosets come into play.


Comment: Consider the action of $S_n$ on the Galois ideal. The galois group is defined to be the subgroup that fixes the ideal, that is, the stabilizer. By the orbit-stabilizer theorem, the orbit of the Galois ideal under the $S_n$ action consists of $[S_n:G]$ ideals, each corresponding to a coset of $S_n/G$. Each of those ideals is a Galois ideal, since each one is the same set of equations with a relabeling of $x_1,...,x_n$, and there is no canonical labeling of $x_1,...,x_n$. The Galois group of a Galois ideal is its stabilizer: for the coset $rG$, this is $rGr^{-1}$.

Comment: 
And $rGr^{-1}$ is a conjugate subgroup of $G$, right?  So there is a 1:1 correspondence between cosets and ideals, and then some kind of onto mapping from that onto the conjugate subgroups.  I think we're saying the same thing.


Comment: That is correct. We are.